# Bootstrap treeview node traversing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, treeview, bootstrap-treeview

In bootstrap treeview component I am trying to get specific node values but unable to traverse correctly. any help is much appreciated. Here is my JSON,

```
[{
    "text": "100 - Environment",
    "selectable": false,
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "100.00.10  Arachnids / Scorpion",
        "hid": "M-AMA-HID-1301-009R",
        "showIcon": false,
        "id": "1",
        "nodes": [{
            "text": "In general, scorpions are not aggressive.",
            "hidden": true,
            "risk": "Moderate-High"
        }]
    }
]
```

I am trying to get "Moderate-High" values from sub-nodes.

```
onNodeChecked: function(event, node) {
    var children = node['nodes'];
   //displays In general, scorpions are not aggressive."
    alert( children[0].text )           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! found it after a cup of coffee :)

```
node['nodes'][0].risk;
```